# Run scipt like sudo with Gksudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gksudo

I'm new in linux. I'm try to mount and umount .iso with nemo-script. I put the script `/home/user/.gnome2/nemo-scripts/`. My problem is, with gksudo I only run 1 command like su. Who I can run all this script like su?

```
#!/bin/bash

gksudo -k /bin/echo "got r00t?"
BNAME=$(basename "$NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS")

sudo mkdir "/media/$BNAME"

zenity --info --title "ISO Mounter" --text "$BNAME e $NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS"

if sudo mount -o loop -t iso9660 $NEMO_SCRIPT_SELECTED_FILE_PATHS "/media/$BNAME"
then
    if zenity --question --title "ISO Mounter" --text "$BNAME Successfully Mounted. Open Volume?"
    then
        nemo /media/$BNAME --no-desktop
    fi
    exit 0
else
    sudo rmdir "/media/$BNAME"
    zenity --error --title "ISO Mounter" --text "Cannot mount $BNAME!"
    exit 1
fi
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this. In your script above, you can execute the entire script with `root` permission if you call the scripts itself with `su -c script` or `sudo script`. Before doing this, edit your script and remove the calls to `gksudo` and `sudo`. Then at the top of your script add a test to insure the script is run with an effective root UID. E.g.:

```
#!/bin/bash

if test "$UID" -eq 0 ; then
    printf "Running script as root\n"
else
    printf "error, this script can only be run by root\n"
    exit 1;
fi
```

Then just make sure you run your script as `sudo scriptname` or `su -c scriptname`. Additionally, **make sure you have the execute bit set of your script file permissions**. You can do it simply with `chmod 0775 scriptname` which will give `owner` and `group` read-write-execute permissions and give `world` read-execute permissions. If you don't want it world executable, then just `chmod 0774`.

**If you don't set execute permission on your script**, you will get a `Permission denied` or `command not found` error. You can execute the script by specifying the shell in your `sudo` or `su` call, e.g. `sudo bash scriptname` or `su -c "bash scriptname"`, but it is preferred to make the script executable.